# Joystick library works in comand line, but not as a macos app

Tags: macos, iokit, joystick

I can't get GameController class working with my joystick. However I found a simple library https://github.com/suzukiplan/gamepad-osx using IOKit written is C and managed to get it working in swift console app using the following code for `main.swift`:

```
import Foundation

func  callback(_  type: Int32, _ page: Int32,  _ usage: Int32, _ value: Int32) -> Void  {
    print("Type: \(type); page: \(page), usage: \(usage), value: \(value)")
}

let ctx = gamepad_init(1, 1, 0)

if ctx == nil {
    print("Init  failed")
    exit(4)
}

gamepad_set_callback(ctx, callback(_:_:_:_:))

CFRunLoopRun()
exit(0)
```

Console messages:

```
attched device: Controller
attched device: 2.4G RX
attched device: VirtualHIDKeyboard
Type: 2; page: 7, usage: 227, value: 1
Type: 2; page: 7, usage: -1, value: 6
....
```

Since this is going to be used in a MacOS app, I created a single-view Cocoa app with the following code in Main View:

```
import AppKit

class MainView: NSView {

    required init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: decoder)

        print("Initialising started")

        let ctx = gamepad_init(1, 1, 0)
        if ctx == nil {
           print("Init  failed")
           return
       }

        print("Initialising succeeded")

        gamepad_set_callback(ctx, callback(_:_:_:_:))

        print("Callback attached")

    }
}

func  callback(_  type: Int32, _ page: Int32,  _ usage: Int32, _ value: Int32) -> Void  {
    print("Type: \(type); page: \(page), usage: \(usage), value: \(value)")
}
```

The window appears, but what I get on console is just that:

```
Initialising started
Initialising succeeded
Callback attached
```

No device attachment messages at all!

Also tried an running and additional thread (DispatchQueue) in Main view and in AppDelegate (this time with `CFRunLoopRun`):

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
   DispatchQueue(label: "Joy").async {
        print("Initialising started")

        let ctx = gamepad_init(1, 1, 0)
        if ctx == nil {
            print("Init  failed")
            return
        }

        print("Initialising succeeded")
        gamepad_set_callback(ctx, callback(_:_:_:_:))

       CFRunLoopRun()
   }
}
```

Again, no attachment messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: in `Capabilities` tab for the project tick `USB` for App Sandbox.

Thanks to https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/358820#358820 for the idea.